# (android - Opengl-es) GlTexSubImage2D Hiccup The First Time Called After The First Draw

Tags: android, opengl-es

i have implemented a tile based layer in my game, but after the first time that 
it was drawn, **just the first time** i try to update it (to add tiny decals, like blood splats, craters, etc. thingies that are added to the map and that i don't want to draw separately every loop) i have a huge hiccup of 3~ seconds.

after some test, i have find the only call that hangs.

gl.glTexSubImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, y, width, height, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);

the decal is really tiny(32 * 32 pixel), there is no opengl error after this call, and i really don't get the whole thing (i mean.....the creation of the whole tile layer actually takes much lesser than 1 second, and is done by a thousand of glTexSubImage2D command on a large blank texture.....3 seconds is pretty huge).

i already have a workaround (a "fake" update just before the splash screen goes off) but i really want to understand this odd(for me, at least) behaviour.. :|

(i'm deeply sorry for my enGrish, i hope that's understandable)

```
METHOD: 
    public static void replaceSubImg(GL10 gl, int hwdId , int x,int  y,int width, int height,Buffer pixelBuffer) {
        gl.glFinish();
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, hwdId);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        gl.glTexSubImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, y, width, height, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);
        Log.d("testApps","openglUtil,@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ subImg replaced in "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)+" ms");
    }

    LOG:        
     DEBUG/testApps(3809): openglUtil,@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ subImg replaced in 2811 ms
     DEBUG/testApps(3809): openglUtil,@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ subImg replaced in 1 ms(this is the 2d run)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a ton of tests, i have isolated the whole thing and this looks like just a bug in the implementation of the opengl in the last cyanogenmod(or just gingerbread, i don't have tested this yet....) :

cyanogen(gingerbread, 7rc2) :

- uploading the texture, ~1ms,
- altering the texture, ~1ms,
- drawin the texture, ~1ms,
- any edit, even 1px for 1px, for every texture,a huge delay( depending on how much is big the texture), in my case ~3000ms
- any further edit,regardless of the size, back to ~1ms

on froyo ( stock, frf91)  :

- uploading the texture, ~1ms,
- altering the texture, ~1ms
- drawing   the texture, ~1ms
- any edit, even 1px for 1px, for every texture, a little delay( depending on how much
  is big the texture), in my case ~80ms
- any further edit,regardless of the size, back to ~0ms

there is anyway a little delay, but understandable this time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but:

Do you have `gl.glTexSubImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, y, width, height, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);` code in every iteration? That call is pretty expensive and it shouldn't be iterated every frame (it's like you're creating the texture every time you draw).

You need to load your textures in the `onSurfaceCreated` callback, store your `GL pointer` and assign that pointer to a `Texture` object (an object that just holds the pointer into `OpenGL` memory).

After that you can just bind it using `glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, yourPointer);`.

Comment: no it's not the case. i only have gl.glTexSubImage2D called when, let's say, a glass is broken, and i need to have the glass fragments added to the map. just one time. in every iteration then i just draw the texture without modifing it, just binding (exactly like you say).

Comment: @user656405: Could you try to elaborate?

Comment: i have a 2d top down game engine. occasionally, i need to add some "gore" and stuff on the level, but i don't want to draw primitives all around every iteration. in this case, i just alter the texture, calling the gltexsubimage when needed.

Comment: @user656405: That's one solution. The recommended way that is top-notch in game development is to use a special pattern for this, called Memory Pools. With that pattern you can access the pool when you need it (and still you don't have to iterate through it). This pattern ensures that you're allocating all your resources when you're bootstraping your game. For information about this topic, see: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html

Comment: @user656405: You have a hiccup in your game during the time when you're playing. That's probably because your `glTexSubImage2D()` which is an expensive call.

Comment: look at the log i have added to the question :| it's not that. (it's not the same pixelbuffer, and the 3~ sec delay only occour the first time in the whole execution )

Comment: @RedBeard: I'm with you now. One thing, before editing the texture with that method - have you first created it with `glTexImage2D()`?

Comment: @RedBeard: That's wierd. One thought, is `pixelBuffer` an `OpenGL` pointer to the texture or is it a `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: it's a bytebuffer.  uhm ... there is actually a way to do that with a texture pointer ?

Comment: @RedBeard: No, that's no way to do that, just checking. However, in bootstrap, can you post a piece of code?

Comment: i have added the initialization of the layer. note that this is done before anything (except the splash screen) is drawn, and every call to replacesubimg takes like 1ms. then the game start, 3 sec hang, and then again 1 ms per call.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL instructions can be pipelined and may not be executed immediately. It seems likely that the `glTexSubImage2D` call itself is fast, but has to wait for some other operation to complete.

To figure this out, it might be instructive to call `glFinish` after some major operations, and see when *that* takes a long time. You may find that the actual time is spent elsewhere... for example, in a thousand `glTexSubImage2D` calls?

Comment: uhm i will test that, but i doubt it. 
i mean....the thousand calls is finished for sure, as i actually see the whole layer drawed on screen. 

and the delay actually happen the first time i have to paste a decals, even if i wait for 5 minute after the start of the game. and everytime, 3 sec ( 2780~3020 ms}

Comment: tested, i have added glfinish just before initializing the time variable, and i get the 3 second hang as well :\